# Why does my Loop mechanism not work?

Tags: java, loops

Sorry if this is a very closed question that won't be useful to others, but I'm just stumped by this bug and I haven't been able to solve it for weeks!

I am working on a wave based survival game and am currently working on a spawning mechanism.
The code I wrote works perfectly for one wave, but somehow doesn't restart for further waves.
I have written the code below:

```
public void run() {
    while (ingame) {
        if (enemyList.isEmpty()) {
            stopSpawn = false;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                spawnNewEnemy();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted");
            }
        } else {
            if (!enemyList.isEmpty() && !stopSpawn) {
                // getEnemyAmount returns the amount of enemies that should be spawned this wave
                for (int enemiesSpawned = 0; enemiesSpawned < getEnemyAmount(); enemiesSpawned++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                    System.out.println(currentWave);
                    spawnNewEnemy();
                }
                stopSpawn = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the spawnNewEnemy method

```
 public void spawnNewEnemy() {
    Random spawn = new Random();
    int spawnX = spawn.nextInt(500);
    int spawnXTest = b.bX - spawnX;
    if (spawnXTest < 20) {
        spawnX = spawnX + 20;
    } else {
    }
    int spawnY = spawn.nextInt(500);
    int spawnYTest = b.bX - spawnY;
    if (spawnYTest < 20) {
        spawnY = spawnY + 20;
    } else {
    }
    spawnY = spawnY + 20;
    spawnX = spawnX + 20;
    enemyList.add(new Enemy(spawnX, spawnY));
}
```

Comment: What isn't working about it? Getting any exceptions?

Comment: Can you explain what the bug is? It's not obvious what your problem is.

Comment: You are actually doing: `if (enemyList.isEmtpy()){} else { if (!enemyList.isEmpty()){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can read the following in your code:

- If the list of enemies is empty, you set `stopSpawn` to false and spawn an enemy.
- That triggers your else-statement.
- There, you spawn enemies based on the enemy count.
- `stopSpawn` is set to true, thus your else-statement doesn't get triggered anymore.
- Nothing happens anymore untill your enemylist is empty.
- If your enemylist is empty again, you start over.

The logics seems ok, so I'm thinking either the way you spawn enemies through `spawnNewEnemy()` is faulty, or the way you remove enemies from the `enemyList` is faulty. I see neither of that code so that is as far as I can go in this answer.

Comment: I agree in the part that without knowing `spawnNewEnemy()`, `getEnemyAmount()` code and other code that reads / writes `stopSpawn`, `enemyList` we will not be able say what is the problem for sure.

Comment: It can't be the isEmpty clause since I just tested it, returning that the List is in fact empty after a wave is cleared! However, if it helps, I've added some code to the question

Comment: If you are sure that isn't the case, then how does removing an enemy work? My best guess is that that isn't going well. Have you thought about Debuglogging `enemyList.size()`? Or watching the value while debugging? Then you'll see how much enemies you have in the list, and probably see what is going wrong in your application.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem with a loop is in `stopSpawn` value.

You set it to `true` after the first wave and likely not setting to `false' before starting the next wave.

Comment: I don't think that is entirely true. See my answer for a written logic about what is happening in the code. Feel free to comment your thoughts about it.